# "Your explorers failed to find anyone.", what I need to find someone?

Tags: kittens-game

I have only 3 trading possibilities, Lizards, Sharks and Griffins. I have 13 Tradepost, yet I can't find anyone else. The game doesn't suggest that you can only have 3 trading options either, so, what I need to find someone else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per the [wiki page on trading](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Trade), there are currently seven races to trade with. The three you have are likely the Lizards, Sharks, and Griffins, all of which only require Year 20. The others' requirements are as follows:

- Nagas: 1500 culture
- Zebras: Own a trade ship
- Spiders: 100 trade ships, 125k max science
- Dragons: Nuclear Fission researched
- Leviathans: Black Pyramid researched

Also, note that while exploring is listed as costing 1000 Catpower, failed exploration only costs 100; if you're ever uncertain whether another race can be found, this reduced failure cost is intentional, to let you explore a few times to see if it works.