# Send Explorers costs 100 catpower

Tags: kittens-game

Is it just me or does sending explorers only cost 100 catpower in the latest build? Or is this because they didn't actually find anyone?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, although it's certainly related to the linked question.  This is "Why does exploring say it costs 1000 catpower but only actually costs 100?", the linked question is "Why can't my explorers find new civilizations?"  If you don't already know both answers, they're not even similar - and we're assuming anyone who searches for this question *doesn't* already know the answer, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because they didn't find anyone.  It requires 1000 catpower to send them, but if they fail to find a new tribe, you only lose 100 and keep the other 900.

Comment: WOOHOO!! What defines when I can find a new civ?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184297/your-explorers-failed-to-find-anyone-what-i-need-to-find-someone

Comment: And for the full list, see [here](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Trade), which will probably be updated when a change is made.

Comment: I thought you get refunded 950 if they don't find anyone, not 900...

Comment: @Schism It was definitely 900 when I was playing a few days ago.

Comment: @Powerlord Ah, okay. I only ever saw it mentioned in the [0.3.3.2 patch notes](http://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/250y4b/v_0332_trade/), where it was 950.